# JobPosting structured data: can hiringOrganization be left blank?

Tags: structured-data

I know this question was already asked in the past, but no satisfactory solution was provided.

On Google page about the [guidelines for Job Posting structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#content-guidelines), concerning the hiringOrganization field you can read:

> Recruiter ad with an apply flow where the company is unspecified. This
>   is acceptable because the role is well-defined and the company does
>   exist, even if it isn't revealed. In this case, **the
>   hiringOrganization property must be blank**.

and, lower in the same page, **hiringOrganization is listed among the required properties**. In addition, the validation page returns an error if this information is missing.

It's a clear contradiction.

Being a recruiter and having the most part of my customers that do not want to be mentioned in the job posting (a common practice in this industry), what am I supposed to do?

Comment: It seems like your second paragraph (concerning blank `hiringOrganization`) is a quote, but it's not in quotes and you haven't linked the source. Where is it from? I'm unable to find it except through old references on other forums.

Comment: @GDav Just click on the link which reads "guidelines for Job Posting...". You'll find the paragraph collapsed under the header "Valid Examples".

Comment: Ah, so it is. I'd suggest notifying Google via their feedback form, and in the meantime do the same as all the other recruiters with undisclosed clients. Their listings are making it into Google Jobs, so apparently isn't causing validation issues or triggering a manual action.

Comment: @GDav Exactly what I did. I checked with other recruiters and they put themselves as hiringOrganization when clients are undisclosed. I did the same. Well... I got  a manual action. Now, since it seems there is no way to have a definitive answer, I'll try to leave it blank, even though validation of structured data keeps failing.